# Reputation league - preserve user search criteria

Tags: feature-request, search, reputation-leagues

As currently implemented, user search criteria is reset, every time you change from month, year or quarter, or change time series (different month, quarter, year).

It is reset to a blank string, so you get to type it again.

[image]

It would be nice if the system saved it for you, for true AJAX experience, for while you are on the page. Having it blank again is okay at the next visit or page reload.

Comment: Yup, this can be really annoying...